# How to insert character in between a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, character

I have a col1 in tbl1 which has data as under:

```
C:\ABC\1245_PQR\125\xyz\ROW20MAOSAD12\
```

now I want to insert a '\' after C:\ABC\1245_PQR\125\xyz\ROW and before '20MAOSAD12\'

and the data format is same but it changes in all row, for example -

```
C:\ABC\1245_PQR\125\xyz\ROW20MAOSAD12\
C:\ABC\3456_ADR\515\xpo\ROWadMAOSAD23\
C:\ABC\1547_DFR\255\RDS\ROW14SDFS15\
```

Can someone please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use replace function

```
SELECT REPLACE('C:\ABC\1245_PQR\125\xyz\ROW20MAOSAD12\', '\ROW', '\ROW\')
```

To be more precise

```
SELECT REPLACE(col1, '\ROW', '\ROW\') from tbl1
```

Comment: You might want to match the leading forward slash as well, i.e. find on `\ROW` and replace with `\ROW\ `.

Comment: Hi Donald,Thanks. But it didnt work. It just updated one row not all the rows in the column. I have another col2 which is comman for all the rows I want to update, Can I use it somehow. Thanks

Comment: I added a SQL for you scenario and the one I provided is just a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could consider the STUFF operator:

```
STUFF ( character_expression , start , length , replaceWith_expression )  

SELECT STUFF('C:\ABC\1245_PQR\125\xyz\ROW20MAOSAD12\',28,0, '\')

SELECT STUFF('SomeColumn',28,0, '\') FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeColumn=SomeValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, I made this one - a bit lengthy

-- Step 1
 Select all rows that have ...xyz.... in col1 and col2 is xyz

```
select * from tbl where col2 = 'row' and col1 like '%xyz%'
```

-- Step 2 
-- From the rows above, calculate the start index of ...xyz....... in col1

```
select charindex('xyz', col1) from (select col1  from tbl where col2 = 'xyz' and col1 like '%xyz%') tmp
```

-- Step 3
-- Split the col1 from CharIndex + 3 (size of xyz)

```
select left(col1, charindex('xyz', col1) + 2 ), substring(col1, charindex('xyz', col1) + 3, LEN(col1) ), ( left(col1, charindex('xyz', col1) + 2 ) + '\' + substring(col1, charindex('xyz', col1) + 3, LEN(col1) ))
from (select col1  from tbl where name = 'xyz' and col1 like '%xyz%') tmp
```

-- Step 4
-- Update !!

```
update tbl
SET col1 = ( left(col1, charindex('xyz', col1) + 2 ) + '\' + substring(col1, charindex('xyz', col1) + 3, LEN(col1) ))
where col2 = 'xyz' and col1 like '%xyz%' and col1 not like '%xyz\%'
```